# Простой калькулятор арктангенса на Django

Tags: python, django, калькулятор

пишу простой калькулятор, есть два поля в форме первое и второе значение, нужно на страничку вывести результат вычислений, не пойму что написать в функции после валидации полей формы я получаю словарь cleaned_data но переменные num_1 и num_2 не резолвятся, хотя введённые данные в форму там есть в этих переменных:

\views.py

```
def Atan(request):
    form = AtanForm()
    if request.method == 'get':
        form = AtanForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.cleaned_data
            out_atan = round(math.degrees(math.atan((num_1 / num_2))), 5)
            out_cos = round(math.cos(out_atan * math.pi / 180), 5)
            out_result = round((num_2 / out_cos), 5)
    return render(request, 'landb/atan_convert.html', {
'form': form,
'out_atan': out_atan,
'out_cos': out_cos,
'out_result': out_result
})
```

\forms.py

```
class AtanForm(forms.Form):
    num_1 = forms.IntegerField(label='Первое значение',
                               widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                                   'class': 'form-control',
                                   'placeholder': 'Введите первое значение'
                               }))
    num_2 = forms.IntegerField(label='Второе значение',
                               widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
```

Answer (score 0):

`num_1` и `num_2` во первых находятся в форме. а где где то там, а во вторых в словаре `form.cleaned_data`.

Пример получения `num_1 = form.cleaned_data['num_1']`

---

UPD: Примерный вариант, который должен работать

```
context = {}
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = AtanForm(request.GET)

    if form.is_valid():
        num_1 = form.cleaned_data['num_1']
        num_2 = form.cleaned_data['num_2']

        out_atan = context['out_atan'] = round(math.degrees(math.atan((num_1 / num_2))), 5)
        out_cos = context['out_cos'] = round(math.cos(out_atan * math.pi / 180), 5)
        out_result = context['out_result'] = round((num_2 / out_cos), 5)
    else:
        error = context['error'] = 'Data wrong!!!'

    context.update({
        'form': form
    })

return render(request, 'landb/atan_convert.html', context)
```

Comment: а вот контекст: 'out_atan': out_atan,
'out_cos': out_cos,
'out_result': out_result вне функции, как их передать в функцию

Comment: в какую функцию? зачем? вы все расчитали, просто выведите в шаблоне

Comment: не получается вывести результат в шаблон, `'out_atan': out_atan,
'out_cos': out_cos,
'out_result': out_result` Local variable 'out_atan' might be referenced before assignment потому что они находятся вне функции. В шаблон я передаю контекст и вывожу ключи `{{ out_cos }} как пример`

Comment: что мешает вынести переменные за пределы цикла, или объявить контекст раньше?

Comment: и это уже другой вопрос

Comment: да хотелось бы этот подвести уже к логическому завершению.

Comment: Если не затруднит может напишите куда сдвинуть контекст или переменные. У меня не получается

Comment: обновил, добавил пример

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился:

```
def Atan(request):
form = AtanForm()

out_atan = ''
out_cos = ''
out_result = ''
error = ''

if request.method == 'GET':
    form = AtanForm(request.GET)

    if form.is_valid():
        num_1 = form.cleaned_data['num_1']
        num_2 = form.cleaned_data['num_2']

        out_atan = round(math.degrees(math.atan((num_1 / num_2))), 5)
        out_cos = round(math.cos(out_atan * math.pi / 180), 5)
        out_result = round((num_2 / out_cos), 5)
    else:
        error = 'Data wrong!!!'

return render(request, 'landb/atan_convert.html', {
    'form': form,
    'out_atan': out_atan,
    'out_cos': out_cos,
    'out_result': out_result,
    'error': error
})
```